What, if any, advantages are there of performing recommended mile marker service at car dealerships?
When I look up reviews for service departments of Toyota dealership in Seattle area, all of them have really sub-par reviews. Will I be able to do my mile marker services outside of dealership or should these be done only by the dealership? What is the advantage of doing these services at the dealership as opposed to at a different car mechanic shop?
By "mile marker service", I'm referring to those 5k, 10k, etc car manufacturer recommended services.
UPDATE - I checked with a local auto garage. They said there is a law protecting consumers against these practices and referred me to read about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act

"best" or "good" falls into the exclusion zone of opinions. If you wish to edit the question to only the first question, you'll avoid that consideration. If you do so, consider to add useful information regarding "mile marker services."

Of course you can make your own mile marker service schedule.  In fact, as many fleet vehicle companies know, servicing more frequently than the recommended intervals -- often at half the interval -- greatly extends the life of the car.  There are federal laws that protect your right to use third party servicing without voiding your car's warranty, and dealerships know it.
I haven't taken a car to a dealership for servicing in 40 years.  Whenever I sell one, it's in top running condition that exceeds the condition of other models I see on the road with similar mileage.
I've read many forum post about dealerships cutting corners.  Compare the prices they charge to what independent shops charge and you'll find it is 2-3 times the price.  It really is a culture of ripoff.  The times I have gone to a dealership for quotes or parts, I almost always given misinformation and delays.
When you monitor your own fluid changes, you also control the quality of the fluids used.  There are better than OEM fluids out there, by companies like Red Line and AMSOIL.  It's worth the extra money in the end.

At least where I live, Toyota offers Toyota Relax, which is essentially an extended warranty, for 10 years. However, this is valid only if you service your car regularly in a dealership.
If you use third party service centers, you don't get Toyota Relax. Good luck having any major faults being fixed for free by the dealer.
I had air conditioning condenser failure, with the part and its installation costs entirely covered by Toyota Relax. I only had to pay for the refrigerant because fluids are not covered by Toyota Relax.
Because of this extended warranty, I heavily recommend using Toyota's dealerships until the car becomes 10 years old, at which point you can choose between Toyota dealer and third party service centers. For hybrid cars, there might be some benefit in Toyota dealers, since third party service centers may not know that the condition of the battery fan filter needs to be checked (and if a change is necessary, it must be changed too), and third party service centers may also omit testing the battery health.

It's like insurance: you pay more for normal things, and zero for unusual things. There are lots of service coverage plans for cars, also for homes, appliances, etc. Another way is to have an Emergency Fund bank account, then you get to keep the money if you never had the problems.
